Am i allowed to work as a 3D Modeler
Assalamualaikum.
Im a student Ive recently started working as a 3D Modeler in the game development industry, i wanted to know if what im doing is halal or haram before i continue it. As a 3D Modeler I mainly make weapon and asset model which i sell to developers/ people looking to buy models. I also get hired for games on a long term basis my concern was that if the game im working for contains music and stuff like that and if people were to play it will i get sins? As my models are apart of the game.
The other way is when people reach out to me to make them a model and i make the model but i have no clue of where the model is used and if it gets used in a game which contains haram will i get sins for my model being apart of the game.
Ive recently been hired for a game thst revolves around anicent greek mythology i wanted to know if im allowed to work for the game before i continue.
And if it is Haram and the money ive earned from it what am i to do with it?
This has been on my mind alot and i wanted to make sure what im doing isint haram.
